# If div hasClass with variable name, addClass

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a class to a div that has a class with a variable name.  This is the code I am using:

```
if ($('div').hasClass(this.filterSelection)) {
        $(this).addClass('highlightMenu');
}
```

The 'this' isn't doing what I want it to, but I don't know what to put in its place.  Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly *do you want it to do?* ..*` a div that has a class with a variable name.`* that's confusing.

Comment: I want to highlight the div that's being filtered on.  That's why I added the name of the element being filtered as a class; that way, I can target that specific div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this)` is referring to the entire `document`. This is because `$('div').hasClass(this.filterSelection)` does not have any chained functions on it. So the line `$(this).addClass('highlightMenu');` does not get the `$(this)` value.

try this.

```
this.filterSelection = 'someFilter'; // I am just hard coding the filterSelection here
var classCheck = this.filterSelection; // store the filterSelection in a variable

$(document).ready(function(){
  var $div = $('div');

  $div.each(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass(classCheck)) {
      $(this).addClass('highlightMenu');
    }
  });
});

<div class="someFilter"></div>
```

Comment: Oh I see your point now. So your page has a bunch of div elements. and you want to add the `highlight` class to the div which has a specific class or attribute. is this correct ?

Comment: Exactly.  To that specific div.

Comment: @DwightMendoza Observe the `$(this)` inside the $div.each callback. The callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword this refers to the element. https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: That worked!  I just had to move the 'classCheck' variable assignment outside and prior to the (document).ready function.  Otherwise, the value of this.filteredSelection was not being carried in to the function.  Please update your answer to reflect this and I'll check it off.  Thanks much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156301/discussion-between-sbr-and-dwight-mendoza).